# integer out of range error in BigInteger sqlalchemy column on heroku

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, sqlalchemy, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting sql errors for the following objects.
I'm using a PostGresSql database on heroku

```
class Member(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "members"

    name = Column(String)
    discord_id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True,nullable=False)
    role = Column(String, ForeignKey('roles.name'))
    nick = Column(String)
    rs_runs = relationship("RSRun",secondary='member_on_rs_run')

    def __init__(self,name,discord_id,nick="" ):
        self.name = name
        self.discord_id = discord_id
        self.nick = nick

class RSRun(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "rs_runs"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    level = Column(String)
    dtg = Column(DateTime)
    members = relationship("Member",secondary='member_on_rs_run')


class MemberOnRSRun(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "member_on_rs_run"
    member_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('members.discord_id'),primary_key = True)
    run_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('rs_runs.id'),primary_key=True)
```

The errors I'm getting are here

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange) integer out of range

[SQL: INSERT INTO members (name, discord_id, role, nick) VALUES (%(name)s, %(discord_id)s, %(role)s, %(nick)s)]
[parameters: {'name': '', 'discord_id': 126793648221192192, 'role': None, 'nick': ''}]
```

I've checked and the discord_id is within legal range of a PostGres BigInt which is what I'm assuming I'm getting with an sqlalchemy Biginteger Column.  But it keeps telling me it's out of range for integer.  Obviously I want to use the same ID that Discord is using since that is the identifier for a member on Discord.

Answer (score 0):

Making changes to the python objects that you are using in the sqlalchemy declarative form will not FORCE heroku to update the database.  You must manually blow away the database for these changes to take affect.